# Reuse my custom hook `useFetch` in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a simple `useFetch` custom hook which allows me to call any Url I want :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


export default function useFetch(url) {
  console.log(url)
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) return response.json();
        setData([]);
      })
      .then((data) => {
       
        setData(data)})
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        setData([]);
      });
  }, [url]);

 
  return { data} ;
}
```

In my Main component I'm loading a static list of items.( via `useEffect` with `[]` becuase it's static)

I currently do it via :

```
export function Courses() {
   
  const [langs, setLangs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(config.url).then((f) => setLangs(f));
  }, []);
...
```

Where `getData` is:

```
export function getData(uri) {
  return fetch(uri).then(response =>
    response.json()
  );
}
```

The problem is that I can't (don't know how) I can use my `useFetch` here becuase it can't be inside `useEffect` , and that's why I've created the *additional* `getData` method.

ps -

In other `"details"` component I use `useFetch` perfectly fine :

```
export default function Details({ langId }) {
  const { data: teachers } = useFetch(`${config.url}/${langId}`);
  ...
```

The problem is only in the main component where I don't want to fetch manually . I want to use my `useFetch`. How can I do that ?

I want that Courses will load the static list only once via `useFetch`

Comment: You should be able to use your `useFetch` custom hook in the Courses component just like you do in the Details component... what is keeping you from doing that? What I mean is, it doesn't need to be in a useEffect hook

Comment: @yinken but then  , whneever the Courses component will rerender , a new ajax will be made... and i dont want that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to cache the fetch response (I didn't test the code)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const cache = {};

export default function useFetch(url, useCache=false) {
  console.log(url)
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (useCache && cache[url]) {
      setData(cache[url]);
    } else {

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          const responseData = await response.json();
          if (useCache) cache[url] = responseData;
          return responseData;
        }
        setData([]);
      })
      .then((data) => {
       
        setData(data)})
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        setData([]);
      });
    }
  }, [url]);

 
  return { data} ;
}
```

You can use `useRef` if you want to keep the hooks as a pure function